# Inject service into service on Laravel 8 using reflection

Tags: laravel, dependency-injection, service

I'm trying to inject a service (model repository) inside another service (when I place controller logic).

I would like to inject it with reflection, but I got an error:

```
class UserService
{
    private $repository;
    public function __construct(UserRepository $repository)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }
```

Error:

> Too few arguments to function App\Services\UserService::__construct(), 0 passed in .../app/Providers/UserServiceProvider.php on line 18 and exactly 1 expected

I found this way to inject, but I would prefer to do it through reflection:

```
    private $repository;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->repository = app(UserRepository::class);
    }
```

There is some elegant way to do this better without using Service Container?

Comment: `app(UserService::class)` should automatically inject the dependencies it can. If it causes an error then do share the error

Comment: I know, but I don't want to inject the service on that way...

Comment: Don't try to implement your own dependency injection function. Use an existing one like the one Laravel offers or another 3rd party one. It may sound simple to roll your own but it will get complicated very fast.

Comment: Thanks @apokryfos, I don't wanna implement my own function, I want to use the laravel native reflection injection... But seems like is not possible inside services themselves...

Comment: `app(...)` uses reflection to inject the dependencies. I'm not sure I understand what the problem is?

Comment: As far I know, reflection is inject through the method parameter. Check my first example:

`class UserService
{
    private $repository;
    public function __construct(UserRepository $repository)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }`

Comment: `app(UserService::class)` will construct and inject an instance of `UserRepository` when creating the `UserService` instance

Comment: Yup, I know, but I don't like it. I don't want to use Service Container... Thanks anyway!

Comment: You could have Laravel use it automatically for you if you type hint the class where you need to use it (in most cases) e.g. in a controller constructor or route handler, if that's what you are saying

Comment: Exactly, when you have a service provider and you just inject it on the constructor or method, like a parameter.

Comment: Yes, you can do that because Laravel is responsible for instantiating those classes and calling those methods and will do so via the service container. If you want to have laravel instantiate these things you need to move their declaration in e.g. a controller and then pass them to wherever they need to be